# Hiccup in frequency domain

Tags: soft-question, frequency, biophysics, biology

**Main question:** *What would the Fourier transform of hiccup look like?*

This question is too general so let me elaborate a few possible approaches.

- *Hiccup just as a series of pulses* (of no matter what physical quantity - a signal processing problem). Are they strictly periodic? Isn't there any "frequency modulation"? What would be the autocorrelation?
- *Hiccup as a biophysical signal.* Do you know any measurements done e. g. by [electroglottograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroglottograph) or any device measuring the muscle tension? Some kind of neurogram would be probably possible as well. How do the signals look and how would be the throat area cross-section as a function of time?

Comment: The obvious approach is to download a copy of Audacity, record a hiccup than use Audacity to compute the spectrum. Unless someone here has already done that it's hard to see how we answer your question.

Comment: I count on that. Someone must have done this. I am definitely not that unique in my thinking.